# Mounting the main fs and chroot

Tags: linux, mount, chroot

I've mounted the main filesystem just like so:

```
mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/main
```

& chroot'ed to it:

```
chroot /mnt/main
```

but now when i issue the command `lsblk` i got an error:

```
failed to access sysfs directory: /sys/dev/block: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of filesystems in addition to the "/" that you want as well. You can either use a bind mount or just mount them inside the chroot.

For this error you want

```
mount -t sysfs sysfs /sys
```

I tend to use

```
for i in dev dev/pts sys tmp run proc
do
    mount --bind /$i /mnt/root/$i
done
```

but add and subtract from the list in the for line accordingly.

Comment: `/proc` may be quite usefull too. Can't edit your answer because of the minimal edit of 6 characters :-(

Comment: Indeed. Added proc as I can edit my own answer. Thanks @binarym